# Clickable effect for ImageButtons

Tags: android

How to give click-able effect for the buttons whose background is an image ? Though it functions correctly but its just looking like an image. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create different images and put them in a selector. Take a look at this tutorial for further details:

[Custom Button Backgrounds Using A Selector XML Layout](http://androidwizard.net/2010/02/custom-button-backgrounds-using-a-selector-xml-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for my dice game.

In your XML you can do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/dice1"
        android:src = "@drawable/red_1_dice"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "60px"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "30px" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/dice2"
        android:src = "@drawable/red_2_dice"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "250px" 
        android:layout_marginTop = "-130px"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/dice3"
        android:src = "@drawable/red_3_dice"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "135px"
        android:layout_marginTop = "20px" />
```

In Your MainActivity.Java you can do:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class Z_veselinovic_yahtzeeActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
    Button start, reroll, hold;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Buttons();
    }


    public void Buttons()
    {


        button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice1);
        button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice2);
        button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice3);
        button4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice4);
        button5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice5);

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);
        reroll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Reroll);
        hold = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Hold);

        reroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hold.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View whatever)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), start.getText() + " Game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Random rand1 = new Random();
                Random rand2 = new Random();
                Random rand3 = new Random();
                Random rand4 = new Random();
                Random rand5 = new Random();

                int dice_num_1 = rand1.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_2 = rand2.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_3 = rand3.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_4 = rand4.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_5 = rand5.nextInt(6) + 1;



                if(dice_num_1 == 1)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_1_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 2)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_2_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 3)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_3_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 4)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_4_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 5)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_5_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 6)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_6_dice);
                }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simplest solution especially for round button.

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Or you can also try this

```
android:background="?android:actionBarItemBackground"
```